# Scraping a team stats table from python using BS4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape a table from pro-football-reference, specifically the team offense table from https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/.  Anytime I try the code below I get back an empty list or just a NoneType.  I have scraped other websites like ESPN and have had no problems.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{}/'

response = requests.get(url.format(2019))

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

team_table = soup.find('table', {'id':'team_stats'})
```

I have also tried

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

to see if maybe it was the way I was bringing the data in.  The page does have a bunch of tables so im assuming thats why its more difficult to scrape a specific table.  Thank you.

Comment: The table which you are trying to access is commented in the html code this could be the reason you are not getting anything..

Comment: thanks man I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The data is inside HTML comments `<!-- ... -->`. You can use this script to get them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.select_one('#all_team_stats').find_next(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))
table = BeautifulSoup(table, 'html.parser')

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    print(*tds)
```

Prints:

```
Baltimore Ravens 16 531 6521 1064 6.1 15 7 386 289 440 3225 37 8 6.9 171 596 3296 21 5.5 188 109 867 27 52.1 8.6 245.99
San Francisco 49ers 16 479 6097 1012 6.0 23 10 336 331 478 3792 28 13 7.4 195 498 2305 23 4.6 110 105 939 31 44.3 12.0 146.39
Tampa Bay Buccaneers 16 458 6366 1086 5.9 41 11 353 382 630 4845 33 30 7.2 244 409 1521 15 3.7 81 133 1111 28 38.3 20.7 44.00
New Orleans Saints 16 458 5982 1011 5.9 8 2 347 418 581 4244 36 6 7.0 230 405 1738 12 4.3 97 120 1036 20 47.1 4.1 167.04
Kansas City Chiefs 16 451 6067 976 6.2 15 10 350 378 576 4498 30 5 7.5 211 375 1569 16 4.2 93 107 1029 46 49.4 8.0 265.38
Dallas Cowboys 16 434 6904 1069 6.5 18 7 379 388 597 4751 30 11 7.7 229 449 2153 18 4.8 120 109 1008 30 44.6 10.3 214.77
New England Patriots 16 420 5664 1095 5.2 15 6 338 378 620 3961 25 9 6.1 197 447 1703 17 3.8 110 94 828 31 36.8 7.6 39.62
Minnesota Vikings 16 407 5656 970 5.8 20 12 314 319 466 3523 26 8 7.1 171 476 2133 19 4.5 106 96 895 37 41.9 10.5 103.01
Seattle Seahawks 16 405 5991 1046 5.7 20 14 341 341 517 3791 31 6 6.7 190 481 2200 15 4.6 121 109 882 30 36.9 10.2 90.55
Tennessee Titans 16 402 5805 949 6.1 17 9 317 297 448 3582 29 8 7.1 177 445 2223 21 5.0 104 99 932 36 31.7 8.2 119.88
Los Angeles Rams 16 394 5998 1055 5.7 24 7 342 397 632 4499 22 17 6.9 222 401 1499 20 3.7 92 118 899 28 36.0 12.9 42.09
Philadelphia Eagles 16 385 5772 1104 5.2 23 15 354 391 613 3833 27 8 5.9 215 454 1939 16 4.3 104 100 836 35 35.5 10.4 67.85
Atlanta Falcons 16 381 6075 1096 5.5 25 10 383 459 684 4714 29 15 6.4 258 362 1361 10 3.8 84 119 956 41 41.3 13.4 104.51
Houston Texans 16 378 5792 1017 5.7 22 8 346 355 534 3783 27 14 6.5 203 434 2009 17 4.6 112 111 892 31 37.7 12.0 121.67
Green Bay Packers 16 376 5528 1020 5.4 13 9 320 356 573 3733 26 4 6.1 190 411 1795 18 4.4 90 100 774 40 37.1 6.9 118.40
Arizona Cardinals 16 361 5467 1000 5.5 18 6 314 355 554 3477 20 12 5.8 176 396 1990 18 5.0 109 121 956 29 38.8 10.1 67.36
Indianapolis Colts 16 361 5238 1016 5.2 21 11 340 307 513 3108 22 10 5.7 165 471 2130 17 4.5 131 79 670 44 36.1 11.4 78.80
Detroit Lions 16 341 5549 1021 5.4 23 8 313 344 571 3900 28 15 6.4 196 407 1649 7 4.1 82 113 937 35 33.3 11.7 33.07
New York Giants 16 341 5416 1012 5.4 33 16 311 376 607 3731 30 17 5.7 187 362 1685 11 4.7 89 90 784 35 28.3 18.3 -5.30
Carolina Panthers 16 340 5469 1077 5.1 35 14 335 382 633 3650 17 21 5.3 230 386 1819 20 4.7 82 87 754 23 32.3 16.9 -24.07
Los Angeles Chargers 16 337 5879 997 5.9 31 11 349 394 597 4426 24 20 7.0 220 366 1453 12 4.0 90 103 872 39 39.5 18.5 83.43
Cleveland Browns 16 335 5455 973 5.6 28 7 305 318 539 3554 22 21 6.1 180 393 1901 15 4.8 90 122 1106 35 34.1 14.8 16.54
Buffalo Bills 16 314 5283 1018 5.2 19 7 314 299 513 3229 21 12 5.8 162 465 2054 13 4.4 120 117 927 32 30.6 10.4 9.66
Oakland Raiders 16 313 5819 989 5.9 17 9 315 367 523 3926 22 8 7.1 194 437 1893 13 4.3 104 128 1138 17 32.9 9.9 80.57
Miami Dolphins 16 306 4960 1022 4.9 26 8 315 371 615 3804 22 18 5.7 210 349 1156 10 3.3 64 92 769 41 30.6 13.3 -23.85
Jacksonville Jaguars 16 300 5468 1020 5.4 20 12 298 364 589 3760 24 8 6.0 183 389 1708 3 4.4 85 132 1165 30 33.9 10.2 -14.15
Pittsburgh Steelers 16 289 4428 937 4.7 30 11 265 315 510 2981 18 19 5.5 147 395 1447 7 3.7 75 111 893 43 28.6 15.7 -84.56
Denver Broncos 16 282 4777 954 5.0 16 6 279 312 504 3115 16 10 5.7 162 409 1662 11 4.1 77 110 912 40 32.9 9.4 -11.61
Chicago Bears 16 280 4749 1020 4.7 19 7 297 371 580 3291 20 12 5.3 178 395 1458 8 3.7 85 103 838 34 29.1 10.5 -38.05
Cincinnati Bengals 16 279 5169 1049 4.9 30 14 312 356 616 3652 18 16 5.5 191 385 1517 9 3.9 85 93 761 36 30.3 16.0 -57.73
New York Jets 16 276 4368 956 4.6 25 9 253 323 521 3111 19 16 5.4 162 383 1257 6 3.3 61 115 1105 30 23.0 11.5 -108.92
Washington Redskins 16 266 4395 885 5.0 21 8 248 298 479 2812 18 13 5.3 154 356 1583 9 4.4 74 106 835 20 30.1 12.1 -82.30
Avg Team  365.0 5565.8 1016.1 5.5 22.2 9.4 324.0 354.1 557.9 3759.4 24.9 12.8 6.3 193.8 418.3 1806.4 14.0 4.3 97.3 107.8 915.8 32.9 36.0 11.8 56.6
League Total  11680 178107 32516 5.5 711 301 10369 11331 17853 120301 797 410 6.3 6200 13387 57806 447 4.3 3115 3451 29306 1054 36.0 11.8 
Avg Tm/G  22.8 347.9 63.5 5.5 1.4 0.6 20.3 22.1 34.9 235.0 1.6 0.8 6.3 12.1 26.1 112.9 0.9 4.3 6.1 6.7 57.2 2.1 36.0 11.8
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much.  Had no clue it was in a comment. 